# Change the connection pool with the console

Tags: java, mongodb, console

I'm using MongoDB in a Java project, and I have this question for you  :

How could I change the connection pool with the console for mongodb ?

Comment: What's the usecase for changing the connection pool in the console? Why do you want this?

Comment: By "connection pool", do you mean the client-side Java connection pool?  And by "the console", do you mean the mongo shell?

Comment: Yes, it the the client-side Java connection pool with  mongo shell

Comment: @sdlfkjdlsfj: You change the connection pool for a Java project in the Java project :).  Connection pooling is a feature of the language driver (Java in this case), not the MongoDB server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this on the MongoDB Google Group and I'll re-quote here:

```
You can control how many connections there are with the [MongoOptions class][1]:

The connection pool is controlled in the driver configuration, not through the mongo shell.
```